# data-ng-hide behavior in printpreview of my application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Question**: `ng-hide` is used twice: with `text.name.length` and `!text.name.length`. Under both conditions the content they control is visible on print preview.  Why?

**my view**

```
<div>
    <div class="content" id="printable">
    my name is  <b data-ng-hide="text.name.length">__________</b><b data-ng-hide="!text.name.length">{{text.name}}</b> 
    </div>
    <button data-ng-click="printDiv('printable')">print</button>  
</div>
```

**this is my printpreview controller which show me printpreview of print page**

**PrintController**

```
app.controller('PrintController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.printDiv = function (divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
        popupWin.document.open()
        popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');


        popupWin.document.close();
    }
})
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I made your title much shorter.  If you feel that it does not adequately describe your problem, then edit it.

Comment: `text.name.length` is not a boolean

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, however it is "truthy".  0 -> false, 1 -> true

Comment: I assume the question is something along the lines of "Why does my angular template break when I put it into a popup window with jQuery?"  The answer would obviously be: "because you used jQuery"

Comment: I added OP's question to the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because with your popup window, you have left the realm of angularjs.

Notice in your code how you construct the popup window with its own `html` element and stylesheet?

```
    popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');
```

There is no sign of angular in `popupWin` whatsoever.

Furthermore, there is more to your angular application than just the DOM elements.  When you copied over the DOM to the popup window, did you somehow copy over `$scope` too? Nope.

Attempting to extend your angular app by transplanting the DOM is akin to taking a job where your body goes to the office but your head stays at home:  It just doesn't work.

There most certainly is a better way.  Google `angularjs print preview`.  You will get results like [this](http://avladov.com/post/74334124064/before-printing-angularjs).

Comment: can you show me a demo on plnkr i am little confuse that how to add scope css on page printing..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to hide the name when it is empty, and on the click show the report with or without the name. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uudh2BAHelacCRoqty9H?p=preview) and I don't understand what is not working for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="PrintController">
   <div>
   <input ng-model="text.name" />
    <div class="content" id="printable">
    my name is  <b data-ng-hide="!text.name.length">{{text.name}}</b> 
    </div>{{text.name.length}}
    <button data-ng-click="printDiv('printable')">print</button>  
</div>
  </body>

</html>


var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('PrintController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.text = {name: 'John'};
  //$scope.text = {name: ''};

  $scope.printDiv = function (divName) {
      var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
      var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
      var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600');
      popupWin.document.open()
      popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');
      popupWin.document.close();
  }
})
```